# How to read current page number from pdf using java selenium webdriver the PDF opens in broswer?

Tags: java, selenium, pdf

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class PDFreader {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException{
     WebDriver driver;

     driver=new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.get("http://www.ptutorial.com/java-pdf/java-programs-examples-with-output-pdf.pdf");

     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by current page number ,, DO you mean by total number of page present in pdf file?

Comment: No. current page number. example i have 14 pages in a pdf file i want to know the current page number.

Comment: So basically what you can do is, you can download the `pdf` and then you can use any of the pdf parsing library to get the text out of it.

Comment: Are you going to scroll it down using selenium?

Comment: For example this is my link " http://www.upv.sk/swift_data/source/pdf/vestnik_upv_sr/2016/201604_v.pdf " Using selenium i clicked on one link which name is "Kódové označenia krajín a medzinárodných organizácií " which redirects to 2nd page . I need this current page  number.

Comment: Can any one help me out in this....